# awk insert columns and printing on single line

Tags: awk

I am trying to use AWK to process a comma seperated text file and insert new columns.
I want to split the contents of the second column into three parts and insert three columns
after column B in a new text file.

insert.txt - my data

```
column A, name|ID1234 @ tag1, column C, column D
```

Output I am trying produce

```
column A, name|ID1234 @ tag1, name, ID1234, tag1, column C, column D
```

Code I have tried

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
   FS=","
  OFS=","
}
{
#  Split Column B - twice
   split($2,a,"|")   #a[1] a[2] seperated by |
   split(a[2],b,"@") #b[1] b[2] seperated by @    

   print $1,$2,a[1],b[1],b[2]; 
   {for(i=3;i<=NF;++i) printf $i}
}
```

`awk -f insert.awk insert.txt > output.txt`

How do I format the output to all be on a single line, comma separated with the inserted columns?

Is it possible during output to trim the white space at the begin and end of each column?

Thanks
Joshua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this solution in any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=", "}
{v2 = $2; gsub(/ *[|@] */, OFS, v2); $2 = $2 OFS v2} 1' file

column A, name|ID1234 @ tag1, name, ID1234, tag1, column C, column D
```

We split each record using field separator `", "` then replace `|` and `@` with same field separator in the stores value of `$2` which is variable `v2`. Then we append this changed value of `v2` in `$2` after `OFS` and finally print full record.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with `awk` can be

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=", "}{split($2,a,/[ |]/);print $1, $2, a[1], a[2], a[4], $3, $4}' file
column A, name|ID1234 @ tag1, name, ID1234, tag1, column C, column D
```

using `split()` we split up `$2` field `name|ID1234 @ tag1` into pieces saved in `a` array. Then we print three of them `a[1]` `a[2]` `a[4]` between `$2` and `$3` fields.

The separator for `split()` can be a regular expression, not just a single character: `/[ |]/`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/^[^,]*,[^,]*,/){
  val1=$3
  sub(/\|/,", ",val1)
  val2=val3=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*@ /,"",val3)
  print val2,  val1 ", " val3 substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file
```